# 0xAPI `swap/quote`: Is the `value` ever > 0 for ERC20 swaps

Tags: 0x

I'm working on a smart contract that uses 0xAPI data passed in by the user to execute a number of ERC20 swaps.

I noticed that so far during my usage of the 0xAPI, when `sellToken` and `buyToken` are both ER20 (i.e. not native Eth) the `value` field was always 0. However in the API docs it refers to native eth being potentially used for "protocol fees".

Therefore I was wondering wether I can assume this `value` field to always be 0 for ERC20 to ERC20 swaps, or if not in what situations / configurations native eth protocol fees will arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past protocol fees have been enabled to pay a rebate to Market makers on limit orders. They are currently disabled, but this is the case where you would find that `value` field is non-zero when the trade is not using the native asset (e.g ETH).

Protocol fees are at the behest of governance, so if they are re-enabled at a point in the future you may have issues not supporting this.

These are only enabled for Native limit orders in 0x, so one work around is to disable these if the protocol fees are re-enabled using `excludedSources=Mesh`.